# A remark upon the word insecurity

Tags: grammar, nouns

In the sentence:

"I want to add a remark upon the word insecurity."

and specifically in the prepositional phrase *upon the word insecurity* what is the function of the nouns **word** and **insecurity**? Are they both objects of upon?

Compare this with *a car manufacturer*, where **car** is an adjectival noun. Anything comparable could be said for either **word** or **insecurity**?

Comment: about the word insecurity. Not "upon".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *word insecurity* serves different function from what *car manufacturer* does.

*word* here is not an attributive noun.  It is the object of the preposition *upon*.  *insecurity* is an appositive; it explains further the noun before it.

> An appositive is a noun or pronoun — often with modifiers — set beside another noun or pronoun to explain or identify it.

> Your friend Bill is in trouble.

[Appositives](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/grammar/appositives.html#:%7E:text=An%20appositive%20is%20a%20noun,friend%20Bill%20is%20in%20trouble).